# Checking if the images exist in the remote server issue

Tags: php, image, curl

I am trying to check if my images exist in the remote server. I have massive images (hundreds).

I have tried `curl` and `file_get_contents` function and both of these will freeze my browser because it will take very long time to check.

My structure is like this

```
<?php
for loops{
 $ch = curl_init($imageFile[$i]);

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
       curl_exec($ch);
       $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       if(retcode==200){
          $imagePath = $imageFile[i]
       }else{
          $imagePth = 'badImage.gif';
       }
       curl_close($ch);

?>

//show images in table
<tr>  
  <td> <img src='".$imagePath."'/> </td>  //show the image if the images exist.
</tr>


<?php
}
?>
```

My codes will eventually show the images but it will take a very long time. Are there anyways to reduce the time or other ways to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried file_exists function in php?

Comment: You could do progressive loading by using AJAX to poll the script for images. I am assuming the issue right now is that the page is taking forever to load because your PHP script is literally downloading every single image file.

Comment: @webgal yes. same loading time.  for thatidiotguy what do you mean by using ajax to pull the script?

Answer (score 1):

simple java script code to check if images exist in the remote server

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Isimage(url) {
$("<img>", {
    src: url,
    error: function() { alert('image not found'); return false; },
    load: function() { alert('image found'); return true; }
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="url" name="img_url" onblur="Isimage(this.value);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some servers will not respond appropriately to HEAD requests, which your CURL_NOBODY option is using. They leave the connection open too long. You could try setting a timeout, but most PHP installations only have second granularity for curl timeouts.

Given those obnoxious rules, I would probably put some javascript that attempts to load the file. If the file is unavailable, show the badImage.gif, otherwise show the file.

Not only will this make page load time better, it will also be more accurate, since the client may have certain site blockers or firewalls that your server does not have.